# how to load Alignment format in python?

Tags: python, alignment, rdflib

Is there a way to load alignment file to python. If I have file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns='http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#'
xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'
xmlns:align='http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#'>
<Alignment>
<map>
      <Cell>
          <entity1 rdf:resource="http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/id/entity//www.last.fm/music/Catie+Curtis"></entity1>
          <entity2 rdf:resource="http://discogs.dataincubator.org/artist/catie-curtis"></entity2>
        <relation>=</relation>
        <measure rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1.0</measure>
      </Cell>
    </map>
<map>
      <Cell>
          <entity1 rdf:resource="http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/id/entity//www.last.fm/music/Bigelf"></entity1>
          <entity2 rdf:resource="http://discogs.dataincubator.org/artist/bigelf"></entity2>
        <relation>=</relation>
        <measure rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.8</measure>
      </Cell>
    </map>
<map>
      <Cell>
          <entity1 rdf:resource="http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/id/entity//www.last.fm/music/%C3%81kos"></entity1>
          <entity2 rdf:resource="http://discogs.dataincubator.org/artist/%C3%81kos"></entity2>
        <relation>=</relation>
        <measure rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.9</measure>
      </Cell>
    </map>
</Alignment>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to keep confidence value as well as triple:
Subject:http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/id/entity//www.last.fm/music/Catie+Curtis
Predicate:owl:SameAs
Object:http://discogs.dataincubator.org/artist/catie-curtis
Confidence:1.0

I was trying to do it with RDFlib, but did not managed to.
Any suggestions will help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with Redland libraries:
http://librdf.org/docs/python.html

```
import RDF
parser = RDF.Parser(name="rdfxml")
model = RDF.Model()
parser.parse_into_model(model, "file:./align.rdf", None)
```

And then query the **model** variable. For example, in order to retrieve all the alignments and return their measure, the query is the following:

```
for statement in RDF.Query("SELECT ?a ?m WHERE {?a a <http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#Cell> ; <http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#measure> ?m. }",query_language="sparql").execute(model):
print "cell: %s measure:%s"%(statement['a'],statement['m'])
```

The result will contain an iterator of dictionary objects  (variable name , result) and it will be printed out as follows:

```
cell: (r1301329275r1126r2) measure:1.0^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
cell: (r1301329275r1126r3) measure:0.8^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
cell: (r1301329275r1126r4) measure:0.9^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
```

APIs in python for retrieving Nodes content can be retrieved here: http://librdf.org/docs/python.html
   For an overview of the SPARQL query language you can read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/

Comment: thanks, but it did not worked for me, while parsing it returns: RedlandError: 'Parser construction failed'.

Comment: I corrected my example. Try this again, although a parser construction failed sound a bit a Redland installation problem. Did you try to translate the xml file into turtle and load a different parse?

Comment: For some reason it worked on the second try, can you please give me a hint how to query it? I've tried several SPARQL queries, but they failed. for example how to get first mapping and its confidence? thanks a lot!

Comment: Done, I hope it will works fine. If you don't want to use SPARQL there is a simple triple patter query API, but SPARQL language it's more powerful.

Comment: If you need to do SPARQL query rewriting using ontology alignments I'm more than happy to know about your research

Comment: No, it is about finding and fixing inconsistencies while linking datasets

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother again :) I did not manage to get subject and object from the cell object, probably there is some method returning them, but I could not find

Comment: Hi, the query I wrote was good to retrieve just the cell entities, if you want subject and object from those you need to rewrite the query. What property do you need to retrieve? I guess entity1 and entity2. Right?
In that case the query should be rewritten like this:

SELECT ?from ?to ?m WHERE {?a a <http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#Cell> ; <http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#measure> ?m ; <http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#entity1> ?from ;
<http://knowledgeweb.semanticweb.org/heterogeneity/alignment#entity2> ?to. }

Comment: Maybe you had came across this error below, it appears when I'm trying to query large files (22.5Mb): librdf error - digest SHA1 already registered
librdf error - hash bdb already registered
librdf error - hash memory already registered
librdf error - model storage already registered
librdf error - storage hashes already registered
librdf error - storage trees already registered
librdf error - storage memory already registered
librdf error - storage file already registered
librdf error - storage uri already registered
librdf error - query language triples already registered

Comment: librdf error - query language laqrs already registered
librdf error - query language rdql already registered
librdf error - query language sparql already registered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nx_red_names.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "nx_red_names.py", line 44, in main
    for statement in RDF.Query(my_query, query_language="sparql").execute(model):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/RDF.py", line 2020, in next
    Redland.librdf_query_results_next(self._results)
RDF.RedlandError: 'digest MD5 already registered'